# Chrome will only download video and not display video player in IIs web page

Tags: google-chrome, flash, video

I have set up IIS on a test server running 2008R2 and created an intranet website with instructional videos for our organization. When I access the intranet website from internet explorer, the text and the layout displays correctly, and windows media player is also displayed and it plays the video. When I run the intranet website from chrome, the text and the layout is correct, but the video will only download. I then have to run the video from the download and then it will play in windows media player.  How can I configure chrome to display the video player, and run the video from the website itself. On the server and the client machine, When I go into chrome://plugins, I have the following installed:

Native client
Adobe flash player
Shockwave flash

Comment: What file type is the video? I'm worried when you say "windows media player is also displayed". Sounds like you have WMV or AVI formats? Chrome plays video in MP4 and webM format. Flash Player is a browser plugin that displays SWF apps (the apps could be coded to load MP4 and FLV videos) but you need to make or download such an app (saved as SWF file).

Comment: The videos are in mp4 format.

Comment: The videos are in mp4 format. I wanted to add a screen shot of the web page displayed on Internet explorer and chrome, but I'm not sure how to do that.. I will explain the problem as best as I can. When I access the intranet website from Internet explorer, it will display the text and each video in the windows media player box. I then click on the play button, and it will play the video. When I access the intranet web page from chrome, the text is correct as in internet explorer, but chrome will not display the video player at all. Chrome just downloads the videos.

Comment: Is there a way I can post the two screen shots of the web page displayed in internet explorer and in chrome?

Comment: You can try **[imgur](http://imgur.com/)** and give links. It's auto-used by this site when you click to upload images into your post (but you need higher rep). Anyways are you using **[video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)** in your page code? That would allow playback in Chrome.

Comment: In the **body** section of your html try adding : `<video width="640" height="480" controls> <source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>` and test in Chrome.